# How to speed up map building with gmapping?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a pipeline that tries different parameters of gmapping and save the results to a folder. After letting them run I can just examine the pictures and see which maps turned out well and chose those parameters in the future. Now my rosbag that I play is 6 minutes longs, so every run takes 6 minutes with the amount of parameters there are in gmapping it would take days to test even the most important ones. Now I know I can replay the rosbags at a faster rate, but when I do that gmapping creates very strange looking maps and they are all distorted. I am using "rosparam set use_sim_time True" before running my bag and gmapping. Not sure if this prevents gmapping of getting the speed up bags correctly. Is there some way to increase the speed at which gmapping can create a map from a rosbag that is being played faster?

Small side question: What would be the most important parameters probably for a differential drive robot to test for. Right now I test minimumScore,  resampleThreshold, particles. Are the other important ones, or a guideline how to tune these parameters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288438/how-to-speed-up-map-building-with-gmapping?/) by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on 2021-05-11**:
have you found an answer to this? can you share how you done this pipeline?

**Comment by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on 2021-08-25**:
In the end I ended up just running many simulations with normal speed after a few days I found some useful parameters, but they will be highly environment specific and sharing them here wouldn't be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the end I ended up just running many simulations with normal speed after a few days I found some useful parameters, but they will be highly environment specific and sharing them here wouldn't be useful

---

Originally posted by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) with karma: 142 on 2021-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zuhair95](https://answers.ros.org/users/87984/zuhair95/) on 2022-07-23**:
Hi mate,
Did you publish a work related to gmapping parameters ?
Thanks.